# Mulitple processes launched by mpirun at different times within a single slurm allocation

Tags: mpi, openmpi, slurm, hpc

I am trying to launch multiple mpirun commands from within a single slurm allocation but launching at different times and with different core counts.

At the minute the script launches something like

```
mpirun -np 2 python parallel_script.py input1
mpirun -np 3 python parallel_script.py input2
```

Doing this naively leads to all the processes being launched on the same (0-n) cores. This can be fixed for a single node by turning off process binding, but it seems there is no way to extend this to multiple node jobs.

Is there any easy mechanism to tell it to keep track of which cores are in use? Alternatively, is there a way to specify an offset to the mpi mapping so as to specify that I want the process to actually launch on logical core X rather than logical core 0.

I'm trying to avoid having to rely too heavily on the scheduler implementation here so as this is useful on more than one system.

Comment: By trying to avoid relying on the scheduler, you will end up scripting your own scheduler ... Have a look at the flux framework, in your use case, it can basically starts its own private scheduler inside one SLURM allocation, and then you can simply `flux mini run -n 2 python ...` and Flux will take care of running your (sub) jobs on non adjacent set of cores.

Comment: It's more that I don't want to put a whole load of code to deal with each scheduler/machine. Most users would expect to see a script run without making additional batch system allocations. I'll have a look into flux, thanks!